# Is there any way of getting headers from inputstream object in Android?

Tags: android, image, header, fetch

I want to get the header information from a webservice call. That service returns a image but need to also get the header information. For getting the image I simply pass inputstream to decodeStream method. How can one get the headers too from that?

Regards
Sunil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the code that does HTTP requests. Perhaps it's something along the lines of

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream is = entity.getContent();

return is;
```

(error handling and other details omitted in this snippet). Look up [HttpResponse](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html) documentation, its `getFirstHeader` method is your friend!